# Métodos estáticos en Java

Tags: java, java-8

¿Se pueden utilizar métodos estáticos para que el código sea mas legible?.

De ser así, ¿como se podría cambiar un atributo de la clase con un método estático?.

```
public class Coche {
    private ListaAverias la;
    private listaPiezas piezas;
    private String color;
    private boolean roto=false;

public void update() {
    pintarPiezas(piezas,color);
    arreglarAveria(la);
    destrozar(roto);
}

public static void pintarPiezas(listaPiezas piezas,String color){
 mucho codigo...
}

public static void arreglarAveria(ListaAverias la){
 mucho codigo...
}

public static void destrozar(boolean roto){
 roto=true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los métodos y atributos estáticos, o de clase, no existen para hacer más legible el código.

Lo atributos de este tipo, al pertenecer a la clase en si y no a una intancia concreta, permiten que todas las instancias de la misma clase compartan el valor de este atributo. Lo que quiere decir que en una instancia `a` modificas el valor de un atributo estático, una instancia `b` también verá reflejado este cambio, puesto que realmente se hace a nivel de la clase.

```
class Test {
    public static int num;
}

Test a = new Test();
Test b = new Test();
a.num = 9;

System.out.println(b.num); // Imprime 9
```

Por tal motivo, y aunque se pueda hacerse, es más recomendable acceder a estos atributos a través de la clase y no de una instancia concreta.

Test.num = 7;

En el caso de los métodos, al pertenecer a la clase en si, no se les permite la manipulación de atributos de instancia (aquellos que no son estáticos) puesto que la VM no sabría en cual de todas las instancias modificar dicho atributo.

```
class Test {
    public int num;

    public static void incrementa() {
        num++;// Error porque se está accediendo a un atributo no estático
    }
}
```

Por todo lo dicho, **NO es correcto** declarar los atributos de una clase como estáticos si estos deben almacenar diferentes valores en cada una de las diferentes instancias de dicha clase. En el caso de los métodos ocurre los mismo, **NO es correcto** declararlos como estáticos si estos modifican o manipulan el estado de la instancia concreta (esto es que requiere para su funcionamiento la manipulación de atributos NO estáticos).

Comment: Se debe inicializar el puntero implicito `Test a = new Test()`, de lo contrario, el compilador dará el siguiente error: 
`error: variable a might not have been initialized a.num = 9;`

Comment: Tienes razón, errata mía. Gracias por la corrección.

Comment: Gracias, ya he recapacitado, simplemente quería hacer un método dentro de un objeto y no se porque estaba empeñado en hacerlo con un static he hecho un método privado y ya esta.

Answer (score 1):

Los métodos estáticos solo pueden leer/escribir atributos estáticos, no de instancia. Si quieres que el método pueda hacer alguna modificación a un atributo de instancia, deberás agregar un parámetro adicional para que haga referencia al objeto actual.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Coche
{
   private int nroRuedas;
   private boolean roto;
   private int placa;
   public static void DetectarSiEstaRoto()
   {
       roto = true; //error.
       System.out.println(roto); //error.
   }
}
```

En ese ejemplo dará un error de compilación, puesto porqué no hay una referencia al objeto. No sería posible asignar un 10 a la variable roto, ya que necesitamos saber en que dirección de memoria se encuentra. Ahora con este ejemplo, te lo voy a comprobar.

Imagínate que nuestro objeto está diseñado así en la RAM:

```
Direcciones de memoria: |0x04|       |0x08|    |0x12|
Atributos:              nroRuedas     roto      placa
```

Para poder leer/escribir en el atributo `roto`(que en realidad es la dirección `0x08`), necesitaría de un puntero que tenga una referencia a la dirección base del objeto Coche, de ese modo, podría desplazarme a la dirección `0x08` y asignar el respectivo dato.

Esta es la razón principal del porqué el ejemplo de arriba no funcionaría porqué necesitamos tener como parámetro un puntero implícito (en Java no existe punteros, pero internamente si) que haga referencia a la dirección base del objeto instanciado.

El código corregido sería así:

```
class Coche
{
   private int nroRuedas;
   private boolean roto;
   private int placa;
   public static void DetectarSiEstaRoto(Coche coche)
   {
       coche.roto = true; 
       System.out.println(coche.roto); 
   }
}
```

El parámetro `coche` es la variable de instancia o puntero implícito que te ayudará a tener la referencia del objeto Coche y de ese modo podrás hacer cualquier modificación a un atributo no estático.